# how to find username and key in twitter in ios5.0 iphone

Tags: iphone, ios5, twitter

Hi I am successfully integrated twitter in my iphone app with ios5.0.
My question is i have login with two accounts in twitter in ios 5.0 then for tweet from my app how  i am know about which user tweeted or user id of Active account

Answer (score 0):

use this methods to get the userinfo

```
- (void) storeCachedTwitterOAuthData: (NSString *) data forUsername: (NSString *) username 
{  
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];  
    [defaults setObject: data forKey: @"authData"];  
    [defaults synchronize];  
}  

- (NSString *) cachedTwitterOAuthDataForUsername: (NSString *) username 
{  
    return [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey: @"authData"];  
}
```

and also

```
- (void)userInfoReceived:(NSArray *)userInfo forRequest:(NSString *)connectionIdentifier 
{
    NSLog(@"User Info Received: %@", userInfo);
}
```

we will get the username here

Answer (score 0):

in the `TWTweetComposeViewController` you can get a picker shown in image and you can select one of your account from it.

[image]

when you are tweeting directly , with the help of ACAccount you can get it by

```
+ (void)pritnUserName {
// Create an account store object.
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];

// Create an account type that ensures Twitter accounts are retrieved.
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

// Request access from the user to use their Twitter accounts.
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    if(granted) {
        // Get the list of Twitter accounts.
        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        // For the sake of brevity, we'll assume there is only one Twitter account present.
        // You would ideally ask the user which account they want to tweet from, if there is more than one Twitter account present.
        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
            // Grab the initial Twitter account to tweet from.

            for (int i = 0 ; i < [accountsArray count] ;i++){
                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:i];
                NSLog(@"username :%d is %@",i+1,twitterAccount.username);

            }

        }
    }
}];

[accountStore release];
```

}